# How to run an AWS CLI: Elastic Beanstalk Wait command in Azure DevOps

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

The structure of the wait command is:

```
$ aws <command> wait <subcommand> [options and parameters]
```

However in DevOps it only seems to support:

```
$ aws <command> <subcommand> [options and parameters]
```

See example below where there is a Command and Subcommand. Where does the Wait go? I'm trying to run this command https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/elasticbeanstalk/wait/environment-updated.html

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to set the Subcommand to wait and move the environment-updated down into the Options and parameters

[image]

Comment: Thanks for sharing your solution here,  would you please accept your solution as the answer? So it would be helpful for other members who get the same issue to find the solution easily. Have a nice day:)

Answer (score 0):

It looks that you want be able to do this using extension. However, you have aws CLI installed on the agent so what you need is to setup few [variables](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vsts/latest/userguide/getting-started.html) and then call your commands from powershell step.

> Supply standard AWS environment variables in the build agent process
> You can specify credentials with standard named AWS environment variables. These variables can be used to get credentials from a custom credentials store.
>
> The following are all the supported standard named AWS environment variables:
>
> AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID – IAM access key ID.
>
> AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY – IAM secret access key.
>
> AWS_SESSION_TOKEN – IAM session token.
>
> AWS_ROLE_ARN – Amazon Resource Name (ARN) of the role you want to assume.
>
> AWS_REGION – AWS Region code, for example, us-east-2.

You can also create a feature request on [github](https://github.com/aws/aws-toolkit-azure-devops) to support `wait` command by extension.

Comment: I omitted the credentials for security. I found that I need to add the wait command at the start of the Options and parameters box.

Comment: Are you saying if I just load those ENV variables in a build task, I can run Powershell commands? Could I also run bash commands? I am just getting my bash commands working by using the aws bash cli, but I am not seeing any output.